# Looking for a C# Regex pattern matching for a series of lines

Tags: c#, regex, match, line

I am presented with a data file and in the file I have a line I need to match, then I'll read the next few lines until I find this match again.

Here are the various structures of the lines I need to match:

```
69 1.0 PKS-EKC-FlYCTRK--Y 2,110.28 2,110.28
70 2.0 ACS-PMM 31.75 63.50
72 1.0 PKS-TR1-CRD 308.14 308.14
73 1.0 QTC-01HZZ-RBER058- 1,725.57 1,725.57
74 1.0 MGS-05B-4TC-120--8 1,222.84 1,222.84
75 1.0 ACS-VGY 98.60 98.60
76 2.0 ACS-VGG 27.27 54.53
77 2.0 ACS-VGQ 110.93 221.86
78 2.0 ECS-ENM--845 1,294.18 2,588.36
80 1.0 FREIGHT 4,188.00 4,188.00
```

Here is what I have thought of so far but it only matches one line, I need to match them all.

```
(\d{2})\s(\d{1}.\d{1})\s(\w+?-\w+?-\w+?--\w)\s(\d+?,\d+.\d+)\s(\d+?,\d+.\d+)
```

Comment: Could you get away with something super simple like `^(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)$`? What's are some examples of lines you don't want to match?

Comment: `{1}` is always redundant and `+?` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: Now, you didn't really explain the rules that govern the structure of these lines, but maybe this is a good start: `^(\d{2})\s(\d.\d)\s(\w+(?:-+\w+)*(?:--\w)?-?)\s((?:\d+,)?\d+.\d+)\s((?:\d+,)?\d+.\d+)$`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/c9e0fv/1

Comment: For this input I'd use eg: [`^(\d\d)\s(\d.\d)\s([\w-]+)+\s(\b[\d.,]+)\s(\b[\d.,]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/19oAuM/1) - Many solutions, all depends on level of match-accuracy :)

Comment: Can you show example of few lines that this is not suppose to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love a good regex problem. Solved!

```
^(\d{2})\s(\d\.\d)\s(\S*)\s((\d*\,\d*.\d{2})|(\d*.\d{2}))\s((\d*\,\d*.\d{2})|(\d*.\d{2}))$
```

There are always two digits at the start:

```
^(\d{2})
```

Followed by a number with one decimal place:

```
(\d\.\d)
```

Followed by some string of non-space characters:

```
(\S*)
```

Using OR to deal with different numeric structures:

```
((\d*\,\d*.\d{2})|(\d*.\d{2}))
```

regex101.com is your friend.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  These answers are great!

Answer (score 1):

You could examine the lines like this:

```
bool IsThisIt(string line)
{
    var parts = line.Split(' ');

    if(parts.Length != 5) return false;

    // Number
    if(!int.TryParse(parts[0], out var _)) return false;

    // Type
    if(!decimal.TryParse(parts[1], out var _)) return false;
    

    // Price 1 
    if(!decimal.TryParse(parts[3], out var _)) return false;

    // Price 2
    if(!decimal.TryParse(parts[4], out var _)) return false;

    return true;
}
```